# for some reason. after colliding with a tile from x axis the scrolling gets messed up. from y axis the scrolling is fine

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, collision

The scrolling code : (ps it affects the tiles x and y + the characters x and y)

```
        scroll[0]+=(atom.rect.x-scroll[0]-(width/2)+50)/20
        scroll[1]+=(atom.rect.y-scroll[1]-(height/2)+50)/20
```

the collision code:

```
def collision_move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types={"Top":False,"Bottom":False,"Left":False,"Right":False}
    rect_temp=pygame.Rect(rect.x,rect.y,atom.width,atom.height-1)
    rect_temp.x+=movement[0]
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        rect.x+=movement[0]
        if movement[0]>0:
            rect.right=tile.left
            collision_types["Right"]=True
        elif movement[0]<0:
            rect.left=tile.right
            collision_types["Left"]=True
    rect_temp=pygame.Rect(rect.x,rect.y,atom.width,atom.height)
    rect_temp.y+=movement[1]
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        rect.y+=movement[1]
        if movement[1]>0:
            rect.bottom=tile.top
            collision_types["Bottom"]=True
        elif movement[1]<0:
            rect.top=tile.bottom
            collision_types["Top"]=True
    return rect,collision_types
```

and movement works like 1,2,3,4,5,6 accelerating 1 by 1 till it reaches six depending on its direction.

Comment: Do you update `atom.rect` after a collision is detected and before you scroll (before `scroll[0]+=(atom.rect.x-scroll[0]-(width/2)+50)/20`)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes i do atom.rect,collisions=collision_move(atom.rect,atom.movement,tile_rects) before scroll[0]+=...

Comment: you could use spaces around `+=`, `=`, `>`, `<` and after `,` to make code more readable. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and added:

```
if collisions["Right"]==False or collisions["Left"]:
        scroll[0]+=(atom.rect.x-scroll[0]-(width/2)+50)
scroll[1]+=(atom.rect.y-scroll[1]-(height/2)+50)
```

fixes collision from x and y and finally finishes off my collision and scrolling !